# glassfish mysql connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish

Hello im trying to build a application using mysql with glassfish 5.0 as a server, so i've added the jar file of jdbc connector and addedd a context.xml file inside my META-INF folder as follow :

```
<Context>
   <Resource name="jdbc/ensasdb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
          username="root" password=""
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ensasdb" />
</Context>
```

and addedd this to my web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource example</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/ensasdb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and to get the datasource i've used this

```
public AdminBean() {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ensasdb");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but im getting this as an error

**javax.servlet.ServletException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : error when conncting to server localhost on port 1,527 with the message connection refused: connect.**

Considiring that it is working on a tomcat server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell the database to listen to what you see as localhost port 1527

Comment: But i want it to listen to my database in port 3306 the problem is that glassfish by default listens to a resources that uses a derby pool on port 1527 but i don't know how to change this behaviour.

Comment: Ah. Your glass fish installation may be broken. Try first with the simplest web app possible.